# How to use Generic Interface in SimpleInjector when registering new TService?

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I have simple interface:

```
public interface IRepo<T>
{
    T GetSingle(int id);

    IQueryable<T> GetCollection();
}
```

And few implementation of this interface:

```
public class ParametersFields_Repo : 
    GenericRepository<Parameters_Fields, MachineDbConnection>, 
    IRepo<Parameters_Fields>
{
    ...
}

public class FieldTypesDict_Repo : 
    GenericRepository<Parameters_FieldTypes_Dict, MachineDbConnection>,
    IRepo<Parameters_FieldTypes_Dict>
{
    ...
}
```

Now I'am trying to register this `IRepo<T>` as `TService` in Simple Injector, what looks like this:

```
private void ConfigureSimpleInjector()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        RegisterDIServices(container);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(
            new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private void RegisterDIServices(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IFieldModelRepository, FieldModelRepository>(
            Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IField_Repo, Field_Repo>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IRepo<Parameters_Fields>, ParametersFields_Repo>(
            Lifestyle.Scoped);
    }
```

But in line:

```
container.Register<IRepo<Parameters_Fields>, ParametersFields_Repo>(
    Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

I'am receiving error:

> The type 'DbAccess.Repositories.ParametersFields_Repo' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'Container.Register(Lifestyle)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DbAccess.Repositories.ParametersFields_Repo' to 'DbAccess.Interface.IRepo'

Could You tell me what is a good approach to do that?. This if my first time, when I'am trying to use DI in project.

Comment: Is this a C# compiler error, or a runtime exception? In case this is a runtime exception, please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Hi Steven. This is compile error, I can't build application.

Comment: In that case, the most likely cause is that there's either a second Parameters_Fields or IRepo<T> definition. This is something your code here doesn't show.